# Disabling part of a document from editing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a part of the document (the index) that I want to change only dinamycally, from a sidebar, and need to throw an error/warning when someone tries to alter it manually, anyway to do so without an onEdit() for Google Docs? I was thinking on time-triggers, but found them to be very unreliable so far...

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll either want to 1) add those users who you don't want to edit certain parts as just viewers who can just suggest edits or 2) have those users freely edit a separate Doc that doesn't contain the parts you don't want edited then merge the body of that into your master Doc with a script or copy/paste.

May want to ask the [Docs forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!categories/docs/documents) how this is being handled too.

Answer (score -1):

I think, for this you can set an onOpen() trigger for the document and you can prompt the user that you cannot edit this part of the document by opening a dialog.

Not sure if that helps.

Comment: I missed that. Thanks!